# Align Text directly to the right of image?

Tags: css, image, text, alignment

[image: http://puu.sh/azjGv/57650c4ccd.png]

Im trying to re-create my mockup from photoshop in code. I've managed to get all elements in the page.

I want a picture and then to have to text directly to the right of it.
Any CSS help would be amazing, thank you in advance!

HTML

```html
<h1>About Me</h1>

<div id="about">

    <img src="images/me.png" class="meimage">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lectus tortor, sodales ac velit sit amet, imperdiet posuere risus. Nam congue volutpat vehicula. Sed convallis tempor orci vitae aliquam. Quisque at faucibus eros. Sed laoreet, orci et ultricies luctus, turpis leo pharetra felis, ac tristique ligula nisl id enim. Nullam porta quam et dolor eleifend placerat. Aenean rhoncus, tellus ut sodales suscipit, nunc enim ornare dui, cursus tincidunt urna nisl vitae lacus. Nunc tincidunt auctor dolor, eget laoreet justo gravida vel. In convallis arcu massa, quis gravida purus vestibulum eget.

</div>
```

CSS

```css
.meimage{
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}

#about{
    text-align: center;
    width:800px; 
    text-shadow:0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif;
font-weight:700;}

h1{
display: block;
padding: 0px 155px;
font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif;
text-shadow:0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Comment: Please include your code directly in your question. Show us what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: HTML - http://puu.sh/azjZz/a07cbf26c2.png
CSS - http://puu.sh/azk1I/3d2fc13127.png, http://puu.sh/azk2E/807746c9ed.png

Comment: Enough with the pictures please. Put the actual code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) to wrap text around an image. Though I'd say it looks a little strange with the text centered:

```
.meimage {
    float:left;
    margin:0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SJTDS/1/

### Edit

If this is a static page and the content won't be changing, you can probably just update the padding on your `<h1>` to get it to align with the image.

```
h1 {
    ...
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SJTDS/4/

Keep in mind that fixed pixel settings can be fragile and break when, for instance, you upload a larger image.

If this is an issue, I'd use a different structure.

Comment: This works! But i want my
    <h1>About Me</h1>
To be lign up with my image. At the moment the text is at the edge like this 
http://puu.sh/azlfb/a2c69e26a3.jpg

Comment: Can you include that `<h1>` in your code? Is it inside `#about`?

Comment: I will update the first post.
EDIT:Post Updated with header css.

Comment: Sorry, I found it. It was not showing in your post.

Comment: I think one of us is mis-understanding the other.
I would basically like my Header and Image to align together, like my photoshop mockup. (http://puu.sh/azmUM/40ba11db1e.png)
I have managed to get the image/text aligned (http://puu.sh/azn2e/67fb882d0c.jpg)
But my image and text need to go over to match the header.

Comment: `padding: 0px 155px;` makes it too far right. It's shorthand for `padding: 0px 155px 0px 155px;`.

Comment: Yay, i got it done! Just by doing padding: 0px 0px 0px 155px;

Answer (score 0):

```
.meimage, #about {
    float: left;
 }
```

Edit: You wanted header floated left too:

```
 .col {
    float: left;
    margin: ...;
  }

 <div class="col"><h1>About Me</h1><img ... /></div>
 <div class="col"><p>Lorem Ipsum...</p></div>
```